# Problem with number guessing game: Guesses arent getting substacted or condition isnt implemented?

Tags: python, while-loop, conditional-statements

For some reason, either my guesses arent being subtracted or the condition in the while loop is not implemented somehow. I've tried loads of things but nothing worked. Heres the code:

```
def guess_func():
    numberrange1 = random.randint(1, 100)
    rightnumber1 = False
    guesses = 3
    while rightnumber1 != True or guesses != 0:
        numberguess1 = int(input('The range is set. Now guess: '))
        if numberguess1 == numberrange1:
            print('Thats the right number! Congrats!')
            rightnumber1 = True
        elif numberguess1 != numberrange1:
            guesses = guesses - 1
            if numberrange1 > numberguess1:
                print('Higher!')
            elif numberrange1 < numberguess1:
                print('Lower!')
        else:
            print('This number is wrong or you entered something else.')
```

Comment: PSA: `x -= 1` is a lot easier to read than `x = x - 1`.

Comment: Why do these variables have `1` on the end?

Comment: What's the actual problem you're seeing? Also, the `else` block will never be executed. Either the numbers are the same (handled by the `if`), or they're not the same (handled by the `elif`). There's no other option. If they entered something that isn't an integer, your program will raise an exception when you do the integer conversion.

Comment: use an `and` in your while condition

Comment: hey paul, yeah i just noticed, how do i fix that?

Comment: @guamrana Is a beginner really expected to slog through that dupe question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if` condition is the problem:

```
while rightnumber1 != True or guesses != 0:
```

This loop will continue running as long as they haven't guessed the correct number, OR they have no guesses remaining.

But that logic is wrong -- you want the loop to keep running only as long as BOTH of those conditions are true!

If they have guessed correctly, then you want the loop to stop immediately; you don't care how many guesses they have remaining.

And if they have no guesses remaining, then you also want the loop to stop immediately; you don't care if they have guessed correctly.

You want to use an AND condition here, not an OR.

```
while rightnumber1 != True and guesses != 0:
```